# C# pass struct with interface to unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++

I have an unmanaged C++ DLL and some C# code that uses [dllimport] to access it. I have a struct that derives from an interface (say Dog : Animal) and on the C++ side I have a class that derives from an abstract class (say Dog : public Animal). I want to have a C++ function that somehow takes in Animal as a parameter, so that I can pass Dog from C# (since you can't use abstract classes as parameters in C++).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use c++/cli to define your object model. That would make it usable by both c# and c++/cli code.

P/invoke essentially does method calls the same way C does. This means they are highly compatible between different languages, but also that they do not support things like polymorphism.

A struct is essentially just a chunk of data in both C# and C, you just need to ensure the layout is the same. But as soon as you start to involve inheritance things become much more complicated since c# and c++ represent objects in completely different ways.

That said, you could still create a c++ method that takes a dog-structure from c# and converts this to the equivalent c++ type.